# I want to store tweets that I find after a search, in a text file

Tags: php, html, twitter, store

Does anyone know how could I save the tweets after searching in a .txt file?
My index file is the following:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <title>Twitter</title>
     </head>
     <body>
  <?php
     require('twitter.class.php');
     $twitter = new twitter_class();
     echo $twitter->getTweets('tomato', 15);
   ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

I'm new to all this so I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to save the tweets:

```
<?php
    require('twitter.class.php');
    $twitter = new twitter_class();
    $tweets = $twitter->getTweets('tomato', 15);
    $currentfile = file_get_contents('tweets.txt');
    file_put_contents('tweets.txt', $currentfile.$tweets);
?>
```

This will append the tweets instead of erasing the data if you don't want to append tweets just do this:

```
<?php
    require('twitter.class.php');
    $twitter = new twitter_class();
    $tweets = $twitter->getTweets('tomato', 15);
    file_put_contents('tweets.txt', $tweets);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have a .txt file with the html inside it, do you have any ideas on how to display it again on a "user-friendly" mode ?

Comment: Yes I do :), email me at c1d@mypin.im and I'll reply with some code that can help you as I don't think I can answer that question here :)

Answer (score 0):

[fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) is your friend. In loop where you echo tweets instead of echoing it write them to textfile

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function `file_punt_contents`?

You could do:

```
<?php
    $file = 'tweets.txt';

    $tweets = $twitter->getTweets('tomato', 15);

    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $tweets);
?>
```

[More info.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have a .txt file with the html inside it, do you have any ideas on how to display it again on a "user-friendly" mode ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create file and write into in php usine `fwrite` , here is a simple code:

```
 $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $twitter->getTweets('tomato', 15););
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I now want to focus on displaying the .txt file on the browser. Any ideas ?